# firefox extension image display in sidebar

Tags: image, firefox, sidebar

I want to display an array of images in my sidebar. The images should be clickable. This is what I got so far in my ff-sidebar.xul file but nothing is shown:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type"text/css" ?>
<!DOCTYPE page SYSTEM "chrome://pos/locale/overlay.dtd">

<page id="posSidebar" title="&posSidebar.label;"
     xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

<script src="ff-sidebar.js"/>
<script src="ff-sidebar.css"/>

<vbox flex="1">
  <label value="&posSidebar.label;" />
<image id="image1"/>
</vbox>
</page>
```

and the code of the css file:

```
#image1 
{
list-style-image: url("chrome://myextension/skin/images/1.png" width='135' height='130');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to load in your CSS file as a script? also the script declarations should be like this:

```
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://rehostimage/content/password_manager.js" />
```

As for the images showing up, have you tried

```
<image src="chrome://myextension/skin/images/1.png" />
```

?